# What is the domain of $f(x)=x\sin\frac 1x$?

Tags: trigonometry

> How can I find the domain of this function? 
>                          $$f(x)=x\sin\frac 1x$$

I know that : 
          $$ -1\le \sin x \leq1$$

I never solved any trigonometric equations.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: For the domain you only care about where the function is undefined. $\sin$ is well-defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, and so is $x$. Where is $1/x$ not defined?

Comment: It is defined as soon as the argument of the sine is defined, i.e. $x\ne 0$, that's all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the argument of the sine function is not defined when $x = 0$, the largest possible domain of the proposed function is given by $\textbf{R}\backslash\{0\}$. However, given that the limit
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 0
\end{align*}

one can define $f$ as it follows
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), & x \neq 0,\\
0, & x = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

so that $f$ is defined and continuous over the reals.

Comment: i didn't understand quite well , how limits involved here ?

Comment: It is just an observation. That means you can extend the given function to be defined over the reals and to be continuous simultaneously according to the right choice of the value $f(0)$.